# Oscillation of nucleons mediated by polarizing electron charge on opposite ends of the nucleus?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, nuclear-physics

Assuming I have a nucleus and its known that there are nucleons inside its shell. Lets say I have an electron that alternates its position from the top of the nucleus to the opposite bottom, back and forth. Will the negative charge of the electron pull the nucleons up and down as the electrons move causing the nucleons to oscillate inside the nucleus.

Comment: What do you mean, *"an electron that alternates its position from the top of the nucleus to the opposite bottom"*? On the scales of an atom, and thus also on the scales of a nucleus, electrons are not localized at all.

Comment: ok let me rephrase, an electron cloud density of that the particular nucleus oscillates about the nucleus, will that cause an oscillation of the nucleons considering the nucleon - electron cloud interaction.

Comment: The latter doesn't exist, either. The solution of electron+nucleus is called an atom.

Comment: It does exist. Doesnt the Kohn-Sham equations help us to understand the electron density around a nucleus.

Comment: This is a good paper that talks about the electron density for atoms and also the Kohn-Sham model 'Kinetic-energy functional of the electron density' Lin-Wang Wang and Michael P. Teter Phys. Rev. B 45, 13196 – Published 15 June 1992

Comment: @NealKD The length scales for the electron and nuclear wavefunctions are different.

Comment: But I'm not considering a wavefunction based electronic structure, instead a density based model.

Comment: The "electron density" *is* nothing else than a particular representation of the wavefunction (unless the model is wrong).

Comment: Yes you are right in a sense. The electron density is a quantum mechanical method to calculate the probability of finding an electron at a particular point. while a wavefunction assigns an oscillating number in space that may be negative, the electron density [rho] is always assigned a positive value which expresses the relative value of finding an electron at a position.

Comment: The hodenburgh-kohn theorems and the kohn-sham equations establish the presences of an electron density around an atom. My question is lets say hypothetically the electron cloud oscillates just as it oscillates around a nanoparticle during localized surface plasmon resonance. Is the force strong enough by the sea of electrons to cause movement or vibrations in the nucleons.

Answer (score 1):

For nuclei in our universe there aren't any electron wavefunctions that would oscillate in the way you describe; the electrons are either (a) smeared out over the entire nuclear volume or (b) unbound.

However, the nucleons in the nucleus can certainly vibrate, and the study of these vibrations and their allowed energy levels is "nuclear spectroscopy."  Your specific scenario reminds me of the [giant dipole resonance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant_resonance).